# Interactive plot for group data using R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, interactive

All,

In order to graph data in many groups(categories):

```
data(iris)
library(dplyr)
iris_new <- select(iris, -Species)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
        geom_point(data = iris_new, colour = "grey70") +
        geom_point(aes(colour = Species)) +
        facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image: The result is shown here]

I didn't make interactive plots before, but I would like to know a way to allow me to make the above graph interactively. For example, in stead of showing the data using `facet`, I would like to have a bottom-like thing or scroll down list function that I can click on to highlight the data of different groups interactively. Each time I click on a certain group name (like those used for the legend), I can see the group data are highlighted and other data are greyed out. Any ideas here? Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered plotly? https://plot.ly/ggplot2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make interactive displays via `shiny`. See here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/

Here's code that you can run:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('species','Species',c("setosa","versicolor","virginica")),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  iris_new <- select(iris, -Species)

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
      geom_point(data = iris_new, colour = "grey70") +
      geom_point(data=iris[iris$Species==input$species,],aes(colour = Species))
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Aha, this is exactly what I want. Thank you!